# Not sure why Mapbox GL setData results in isSourceLoaded being false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, mapbox-gl-js

I have a React app which uses Mapbox GL (without any wrappers). I also display a chart using ChartJS. On the chart, I have a listener for hover events which results in `setData()` being called on one of my map sources. However, the data does not update quickly (as the user moves around the chart) despite being only a single GeoJSON point, and instead I am getting data events with isSourceLoaded being false. Not sure what could be causing the slow updates?

The code inside my hover event listener on the chart is as follows:

```
if (mapReady && activeElement.length > 0) {
  currentEl = activeElement[0]._index;
  const data = {
    type: 'Feature',
    properties: {},
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: workout.streams.latLng.data[activeElement[0]._index],
    },
  };
  mapRef.current.getSource('current').setData(data);
}
```

An [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgHjU.png) of the events giving `isSourceLoaded: false` - note how the GeoJSON data is there, so not waiting for network or anything like that.